# Attributes: @property for Java

Tags: java, objective-c, object, properties

Is there an `@property` attribute in Java like there is in Objective-C?

If there were, could I name the object, then access it's properties through objectName.propertyName?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is no direct substitute for the annotation for the purpose you want..

In fact, all you need to do is define the property as public and then you can use it with objectname.propertyname. However, in OOPs design, direct access of properties field is frowned upon. try reading about accessor methods to begin with.